# Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a Cocoa Touch framework file which I take out regularly from my codebase. It has some helper classes which I uses in some of my projects. It was doing good before the evolution of Xcode 9.0.

When I tried that framework in a project of Xcode 9 then it shows error that the module is compiled with Swift 3.1 so I compiled the whole classes using Swift 4 and tried to use that in a application, it still shows me the above mentioned error.

If I use the same project in Xcode 8.3.2 then it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is in one of external libraries then their recompilation is required. For that one way is:

1. Deintegrate all the pods first:

   ```
   pod deintegrate
   ```
2. Run pod install again:

   ```
   pod install
   ```

Also, clean XCode Derived Data & clean up your project.

Comment: Hi @Peeyush
I believe you have not read my question well. I clearly written, I have made that .framework file from my helper swift class so I am not using any POD file.  Could you please let me know if there are any other solution?